# Seeking results of multi conditions in multi data column, but each condition value is just one of many in a single cell of google sheet

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, random, google-query-language

Please check the file first.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wYq9BEESpu77wvJzQY1AE4Gmr_PhhaNFSik0ZZt8aD0/edit?usp=sharing
My purpose is:

- Generating idea randomly in "Calendar" sheet base on the "Idea" sheet
  The concept is:
- Selecting the condition about Industry & Quality in B1 & B2 in "Calendar" sheet
- Selecting the time will post on each day of week
- Then the idea will be shown off based on these conditions.
  In this case, any cell can has 2+ values.

We can't  split values to single columns because those data can be added more value in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({RANDARRAY(ROWS(A2:A)), A2:G}, "select Col2 where 9=9 "&
 IF(J11="",," and Col3 contains '"&J11&"' ")&
 IF(J12="",," and Col4 contains '"&J12&"' ")&
 IF(J13="",," and Col5 contains '"&J13&"' ")&
 IF(J14="",," and Col6 contains '"&J14&"' ")&
 IF(J15="",," and Col7 contains '"&J15&"' ")&
 "order by Col1 limit 1")
```

[image]